# git init in a git subdirectory

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a git repo which has some subdirectories:

```
~/src
~/src/.git
~/src/mystuff
~/src/otherstuff
```

Now I want to share `src/otherstuff` with someone else. They should be able to clone it and push changes in `otherstuff`, but I don't want them to be able to access `src`, commits in `mystuff` nor even see that they exist.

How do you go about this with git?

Comment: What about using two repos, one a submodule in the other?

Comment: Yes, what about it?  What does it mean, how do I do it, etc.

Comment: See here: [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: I was already reading that page, actually, but I don't understand the differences with `git-subtree`.  It also seems to be geared towards adding in some other pre-existing git repo to my own, which is different from my situation

Comment: Well, your situation is using git in a way it is not intended. :)  What happens to revisions that only affect "mystuff", or revisions that affect "mystuff" and "otherstuff" in the same commit?  You can't just rip a git repo in half and expect it to be happy.


Submodules are for joining external repos together, like svn:externals.

Comment: Would something like this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662753/export-subtree-in-git-with-history or do you want to actually keep this repo in one piece but still share just that subdirectory?

Comment: Hmm.  Good point.  Actually, I don't mind if revisions that change `mystuff` and `otherstuff` in the same commit were prohibited.  But maybe what I had in mind isn't possible, I would be open to other suggestions including changes to my workflow ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making a `git init` within a git repo works: the directory in which you init the *nested* repo simply becomes ignored by the parent repo.

However, if the history of that subdirectory is important, is is best to [export it as a separate repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662787/6309) (as [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78613/nick-veys) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353858/git-init-in-a-git-subdirectory#comment21690750_15353858)).
From there, you can keep both repos in lock steps by declaring that new repo as [a submodule of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194).