# How to change a tracked folder into a git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'd like to change one folder in my project into a submodule.
This is my (sumplified) directory structure:

```
|-app <- the root of git project   
|--themes
|--plugins
|--lib
```

Now, I want to turn app/plugins into a submodule so that I commit changes in this directory into a separate reposiotry.

After setting up a new repo for plugins, I've tired `git submodule add <submodule-repository> plugins`, but then I receive a message the reads

> app/plugins' already exists in the index

Sure it exists in the index since it was tracked as part of the main project repository.

How should I solve it? Should I perhaps delete the main `.git` folder, add `app/plugins` to .gitignore, commit again, and then run `git submodule add`?

This actually raises another question, should a folder that is a submodule of the project be added to `.gitignore` of the project that includes the submodule?

Comment: Git sub modules sound great on paper, but are a pain to work with. Use git subtrees instead.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to answer my own question. Perhaps I posted too soon. Nevertheless maybe it will help some people in the future:

In order to turn a folder tracked in the current project into this project's submodule, I took the following steps:

1. Initialize a new repository in the folder that will later be a submodule;
2. Commit the contents to a remote;
3. Remove this folder from the main project with `git rm -rf <folder_that_will_be_a_submodule>`;
4. Now do the same but with `rm -rf`;
5. Go to your project root (where the main `.git` lives);
6. Execute `git submodule add <repository>`;
7. Remove references to the folder that is now a submodule form your main `.gitignore` (if it has been referenced there).

Hope it will help somebody.

Comment: It helped me, along with https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662787/280995. So thanks for posting it :)