# How to remove a directory level from a GIT repo?

Tags: git

My directory structure looks like this and I want to remove 'uneeded_dir'

```
/myrepo
   /unneeded_dir
       /mycode
```

Everything is under ***mycode*** directory but at the beginning I thought I would need **unneeded_dir** level. Now I need to remove that useless level. Is there a way to do it but still keep the logs of all the files located within? I just move (or git mv) they will have to be re-added.

I'm willing to do anything up to recreating a new GIT repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really prefer another solution that more brutal as it involves recreating the whole repo but for me it is exactly what I for:

[How to move a subdir to a new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811251/how-can-i-move-a-single-directory-from-a-git-repository-to-a-new-repository-whil)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to create a commit moving all the files.  You can do that with `git mv`.

Git will keep track of the movement and your file history will be preserved.  If you move the files and add and commit them **not** using `git mv`.  Git will recognize the rename but the history of the old files will be lost.

Comment: But won't that make me loose the logs? MEaning the files will be like new to the repo?

Comment: As long as you use, `git mv` the history will be kept track of.

Comment: *Regardless* of whether you use `git mv` or not, the entire history of all the files will remain in your repository. Using `git mv` moves the files and updates the index for you in one step. You can alternately use `mv` to move the files, and just do a `git add -A .` afterward to accomplish the same thing. You will not lose the history of the old files.

Comment: But then I'll have to always use "--follow", but I guess there is no other way.