# How do I install git-subtree with Cygwin in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, git-subtree

I'm struggling to install git-subtree with Cygwin and there hasn't been any good tutorials online focused on building from source in Windows. Have you ever had this issue, and what is the best strategy to tackle it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`git-subtree` is not part of a package. However, like `gitk` you can manually
install it

```
wget rawgit.com/git/git/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh
install git-subtree.sh /bin/git-subtree
```

Comment: It is strange that *git-subtree* is just a script file, and cygwin just won't include it by default. Any idea?

Comment: I installed it the mentioned way, but how does I fix git subtree when `peel_committish` is not found?

```/usr/bin/git-subtree: Zeile 568: peel_committish: Command not found.
    fatal: 'subtree' appears to be a git command, but we were not able to execute it. Maybe git-subtree is broken?```

Comment: @SarahManning Thank you. Solved it by updating my cygwin though.

Comment: @davidshen84: It's because `contrib` is generally not included in packages.

Comment: Failed for me on Windows 10